# Erro en suds al consultar a wsdl

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Estoy migrando unos proyectos a python sobre sql 2017, y me encontre con un problema sobre la libreria suds.

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'Python', 
@script = N'
from suds.client import Client
url="https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdXMLserver.php?wsdl"
client = Client(url)'
```

Salida

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0 Error de script 'Python' durante
>   la ejecución de 'sp_execute_external_script' con HRESULT 0x80004004.
>   Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0 Error en el script externo:
>
> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "", line 5, in    File
>   "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\ExtensibilityData\MSSQLSERVER01\2BB630CA-1241-4B83-B33A-195C1B7C98A2\sqlindb.py",
>   line 29, in transform
>       from suds.client import Client   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py",
>   line 242
>       except Exception, e:
>                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more
>   information. Mensaje(s) STDOUT del script externo:  SqlSatelliteCall
>   function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py",
>   line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call
>       rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)   File "D:\MSSQL\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py",
>   line 291, in rx_native_call
>       ret = px_call(functionname, params) RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.

**Esta en la linea en cuestion donde se produce la excepcion del archivo client.py**

```
def create(self, name):
        """
        create a WSDL type by name
        @param name: The name of a type defined in the WSDL.
        @type name: str
        @return: The requested object.
        @rtype: L{Object}
        """
        timer = metrics.Timer()
        timer.start()
        type = self.resolver.find(name)
        if type is None:
            raise TypeNotFound(name)
        if type.enum():
            result = InstFactory.object(name)
            for e, a in type.children():
                setattr(result, e.name, e.name)
        else:
            try:
                result = self.builder.build(type)
            except Exception, e:
                log.error("create '%s' failed", name, exc_info=True)
                raise BuildError(name, e)
        timer.stop()
        metrics.log.debug('%s created: %s', name, timer)
        return result
```

**la version de python es 3.5.2 Continuum.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese código no es válido para Python 3, la sintaxis para asociar una excepcion a una variable local fue cambiada en base a lo expuesto en  [PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/#grammar-changes).

Debes usar `as` para asignar la excepción a la variable local `e`, sintaxis válida ya desde la versión 2.6:

```
try:
    result = self.builder.build(type)
except Exception as e:
    log.error("create '%s' failed", name, exc_info=True)
    raise BuildError(name, e)
```

En Python 2, la sintaxis para capturar excepciones era:

- `except ExceptionType:`
- `except ExceptionType, target:`

`ExceptionType` puede ser una tupla, p.e:`except (TypeError, ValueError)`.

Esta sintaxis es ambigua y podría provocar errores difíciles de detectar, si hacemos:

`except TypeError, ValueError:`  # Sin paréntesis

solo capturará `TypeError` y asignará el objeto al identificador `ValueError`, lo cual además enmascara el built-in.

Para solucionar esto, Python 2.6 introdujo una sintaxis alternativa:

```
except ExceptionType as target:
```

En Python 3, la sintaxis anterior ya no está permitida, en Python >= 2.6 se mantuvo para mantener la compatibilidad con versiones anteriores.

> **Nota**: `type` es una función built-in, no debería usarse este identificador para variables propias. en este caso se una variable local por lo que solo se sobrescribe dentro de la función, no obstante aunque solo sea por legibilidad debería usarse otro nombre o `type_`.

Comment: se instalo la libreria suds con pip, porque instalo esa version de suds en python 3?

Comment: La librería por desgracia no está mantenida por lo que parece, su última actualización es de septiembre del 2010 y aparentemente nunca se pensó ni portó a Python 3 (que hacia relativamente poco que había aparecido) y posiblemente la sintaxis que causa el error se dejó para dar soporte a versiones previas a la 2.6. La causa de que te deje instalarla es culpa de una mala configuración del paquete por parte de su autor.

Comment: Mírate algunos forks que hay de suds como [suds-py3](https://pypi.org/project/suds-py3/) o [suds-jurko](https://pypi.org/project/suds-jurko/) (desinstala `suds` previamente) u otros  clientes SOAP como [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/).